# Error when launch adhoc app in xcode 3.2.4

Tags: xcode, ios

I'm sorry about asking this question again, I looked for many forums, websites about this issue, even if I did follow Apple's instruction at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1710.html but it's seem helpful for me. I upraged my xcode sdk to 3.2.4 and iOS 4.1, everything is well with Development, but when I built adhoc with Distribution, the app can't launch with error:

> Error launching remote program: failed to get the task for process 571.
>
> Error launching remote program: failed to get the task for process 571.
>
> The program being debugged is not being run.
>
> The program being debugged is not being run.

I created the Entitlements.plist with configurations:

```
<key>application-identifier</key>

<string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)$(CFBundleIdentifier)</string>

<key>get-task-allow</key>

<false/>

<key>keychain-access-groups</key>

<array>

    <string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)$(CFBundleIdentifier)</string>

</array>
```

but nothing is changed. Anyone could help me? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run distribution builds directly from xcode. Instead go to the organizer, select your device, and drag the app into the Applications section. Then you can run it from the device as you would any app from the app store.